# Mantine Notification Text Color

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, frontend, mantine

I am helping my friends develop the frontend of an application, developed in `Typescript`, `React` and `Mantine`. We have the following notification code and image:

*Code:*

```
notifications.show({
            id: 'login-success',
            title: 'Login successful!',
            message: 'You have successfully logged in!',
            autoClose: 5000,
            withCloseButton: true,
            style: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
        });
```

*Result:*

[image]

I want the **title** and **text** in the notification to be white.

I tried the following, but none of them worked;

- Changing the `style` attribute to have the `color: 'white'` property,
- Adding `.mantine-notification-message { color: white !important; }` to the CSS that we are using and
- Wrapping the entire app using `ThemeProvider` like so:

  ```
     const theme = {
       colorScheme: 'dark',
       colors: {
         white: '#ffffff',
       },
     };

     return (
       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         ... components ...
       </ThemeProvider>
     );
  ```

How can I make the **title** and the **text** white?

Comment: "*I tried to change the style attribute but it did not work.*" - how did you try to change it? Please add that information to the question, with an explanation about how it "*did not work.*"

Comment: @DavidThomas I added the things I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: (https://mantine.dev/others/notifications/#customize-notification-styles), you can use

```
styles: (theme) => ({
    title: { color: theme.white },
    description: { color: theme.white },
})
```

Comment: I added this below to the existing `style: { backgroundColor: 'green' }` and it worked! Thank you for your help.